# Competitor information / Products and pricing

Tags: php

Is there a way of accessing competitors products and pricing without trawling through their site for each and every model?
Surely there would be a way of getting their back end table??
Just looking for a way to make my job easier, there are thousands of makes and models and I have to research their pricing and details they hold.

Hopefully someone can come up with a solution?

Cheers

Comment: "Surely there would be a way of getting their back end table?" - short of hacking into their backend, probably not.

Comment: Would this be possible to do?

Comment: it's certainly possible to hack into somebody else's system but it's also very illegal.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a web crawler for your competitors website that analyzes product make & model plus the pricing. This is a non-trivial and sophisticated piece of code to write. I am unfortunately doubtful that there is anything you can get off-the-shelf that will do this for you.

Basically, you are looking to write an automated web scraper.